# UIView position does not respect NSLayoutConstraint when altered from viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, autolayout

I have two views, **one visible (grey)** *and* **one hidden (red)**. The visible view is constraint to the `superview` top with a constant of `32`, and the other constraint to the `superview` top with a constant of `16`.

The top of the visible view is also constrained to the bottom of the hidden view, with a constant of `8`. This constraint has a priority of `749`, because it is initially unsatisfiable.

The idea is that the visible (grey) view should be 32 points below the superview normally, but when the hidden (red) view is made visible, the original (grey) view should be 8 points below the other view (red).

I'm achieving this by keeping a strong reference to the `32`-point constraint, and making it active/inactive as I'm hiding/unhiding the view (red).

Here's a picture of my layout:

[image: Screenshot]

This works very well normally, but I've been trying to set `constraint.active = NO`  and `redView.hidden = NO` in `viewDidLoad`, as I need the textfield to display an error if a certain condition has not been met. For some reason, this does not work. The red view is displayed as expected, but the second view (grey) does not move down as it should (it does not respect the `749` constraint, even if the main constraint is no longer active). Here's a picture of the result:

[image: Not working initially]

However, I made the code to inactivate the constraint and display the view run after a small delay (using `dispatch_after();`), and then it suddenly works as expected:

[image: Works after delay]

My question is: why doesn't the view respect the constraint and move down when it is run immediately from `viewDidLoad`? Why does it suddenly work after a small delay? Is this a decent solution of achieving my goal, given I can get it to work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call it in viewDidLayoutSubviews methode not in viewdidload.
autolayout it take some time to load so call it in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Thanks, doing the layout in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead fixes the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I've been stuck on this for far too long!

Answer (score 1):

While using autolayout **- (void)viewDidLoad** will return the frame which you gave in storyboard.

You have to use **- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews** to update the frame according to constraints.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    //Replace self.view by your view whose constraints need to update
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Just calling `layoutIfNeeded` from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is not enough, as the changes I've made to the `constraint` in `viewDidLoad` hasn't been registered. The correct procedure is as **Hiren** pointed out, to do all the layout tasks directly from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. The point you're making is correct though!